# How to set column width in tabularx?

Tags: tabularx, columns, multicolumn

I have a table, how to set width of 6th row, so the widths of columns be 25%|25%|25%|25% ? right now my code of it looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}  % Включаем пакет для поддержки русского
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ |X|X|X|X| }
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{1.Название документа}   & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{add}           \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{2.Компания группы}      & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{something}    \\  \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{3.Филиал/подразделение} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{something}    \\  \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{4.Вид работ:}           & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{something}   \\ \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Общестроительные работы Cекции №10 (2 и 3й этажи)}}  \\ \hline
6.Срок начала работ, согласно проектного плана  & дата 1 & 7.Срок окончания работ, согласно проектного плана  & дата 2 \\ \hline  
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{8.Требуемая разрешительная документация}  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Сертификат, лицензия}  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{9.Необходимость в проведении предварительного аудита} &  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Да} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{10.Лицо, ответственное за осуществление технадзора со стороны заказчика} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Сидоров И.И.} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{11.Контактное лицо для ответа на технические вопросы} &  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Николаенко А.А} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{12.Необходимость в разработке/ внесении изменений в проектную документацию} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Да} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{13.Название проектной документации достаточной для проведения работ}  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{14.Условия поставки}  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{30 дней отсрочки платежа}  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{15.Желаемые приоритеты по порядку выполнения работ}  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{сначала ремонтируем двери склада, потом красим стену}  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{16.Требования к формированию коммерческого предложения}  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Требование 1 }  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{17.Приложения }  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Приложение}  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{18.Участники тендера}  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{ААА}  \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

But I want to have a table which looks like this:
[image]

Comment: You're screwing up the effect of `X` with `\multicolumns{2}{|c|}{...}` etc. This can't work

Comment: @Christian how to fix it?

Comment: Please have a look into the `array` package and `\newcolumntype` command -- it's too much effort for me to fix all the rows etc. right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you know the widths in advance you are best avoiding `tabularx` als if using vertical rules only use `|` on the right hand edge (apart from the first column) otherwise you get duplicate rule one at the right of one cell and a touching one at the left of the next,

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}  % Включаем пакет для поддержки русского
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\newlength\mylength
\setlength\mylength{\dimexpr(\textwidth-5\arrayrulewidth-8\tabcolsep)/4}
\newcommand\sfour{%
\multicolumn{4}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\arrayrulewidth-4\tabcolsep}|}}
\newcommand\stwol{%
\multicolumn{2}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr2\mylength+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth}|}}
\newcommand\stwor{%
\multicolumn{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr2\mylength+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth}|}}

\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}
{|*4{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\mylength}|} }
\hline
\stwol{1.Название документа}   & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{add}           \\ \hline
\stwol{2.Компания группы}      & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{something}    \\  \hline
\stwol{3.Филиал/подразделение} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{something}    \\  \hline
\stwol{4.Вид работ:}           & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{something}   \\ \hline
\sfour{\textbf{Общестроительные работы Cекции №10 (2 и 3й этажи)}}  \\ \hline
6.Срок начала работ, согласно проектного плана  & дата 1 & 7.Срок окончания работ, согласно проектного плана  & дата 2 \\ \hline  
\sfour{8.Требуемая разрешительная документация}  \\ \hline
\sfour{Сертификат, лицензия}  \\ \hline
\stwol{9.Необходимость в проведении предварительного аудита} &  \stwor{Да} \\ \hline
\stwol{10.Лицо, ответственное за осуществление технадзора со стороны заказчика} & \stwor{Сидоров И.И.} \\ \hline
\stwol{11.Контактное лицо для ответа на технические вопросы} &  \stwor{Николаенко А.А} \\ \hline
\stwol{12.Необходимость в разработке/ внесении изменений в проектную документацию} & \stwor{Да} \\ \hline
\sfour{13.Название проектной документации достаточной для проведения работ}  \\ \hline
\sfour{14.Условия поставки}  \\ \hline
\sfour{30 дней отсрочки платежа}  \\ \hline
\sfour{15.Желаемые приоритеты по порядку выполнения работ}  \\ \hline
\sfour{сначала ремонтируем двери склада, потом красим стену}  \\ \hline
\sfour{16.Требования к формированию коммерческого предложения}  \\ \hline
\sfour{Требование 1 }  \\ \hline
\sfour{17.Приложения }  \\ \hline
\sfour{Приложение}  \\ \hline
\sfour{18.Участники тендера}  \\ \hline
\sfour{ААА}  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```